# How to build an offline browser side application?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am looking to develop a web application which has to work in instances where the internet connection of the Browser is broken.

So a hypothetical use case would be:

1. Browser connects to: myapp.com/phone-list and displays it to the user
2. Five days later, with the Internet connection broken, the user attempts to connect to myapp.com/phone-list. The browser detects that it has no internet connectivity and servers up the last good version it has.

Question:
Is there a way to do this robustly across browsers, using, say a jQuery plugin?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: I don't think there is any plugin available. But you can have an ajax call to google or something. Periodically call this ajax,if returns success internet is up else down.Would be lightweight as well.

Comment: @johan, how robust would it be to use HTML5 application cache?

Comment: @johan, could I appeal to you to vote to reopen this question. It seems to have been hit by shoot before your read vigilantism

Comment: @sandy, could I appeal to you to vote to reopen this question. It seems to have been hit by shoot before your read vigilantism

Comment: @Johan actually your comment was the correct answer, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it as an answer, would want you to get credit for it. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, I'm not here for the reputation. Thanks though. Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it. Glad I could help.